# Resize JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, layout, user-interface, jpanel

I am having problem in making my Java Application to resize itself when the screen size changes.

My ui is as follows :

I have a JPanel which consist of a few images and buttons.

I have a GridLyout which i add 9 JPanel mentioned above into the GridLayout.

The problem is the JPanel object seem too big to fit into the layout. I have read  that using a layout manager will resolve the problem however it didnt work in my case.

I have designed the ui using netbean GUI builder and had not make any changes to the properties. I

Any suggestion ? Thank you so much.

**Windowed View**
[image]

**Full Screen View**
[image]

I would like to achieve all 9 JPanel to show irregardless of window size. I have tried using layout recommended in some post.

Adding Jpanel

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
    UserUI tmp = new User_UI("User is " + x);
    mainPanel.add(tmp);
    validate();
}
```

Comment: Post an SSCCE. Tell us what you expect the code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Can we have a screenshot of your error?

Comment: @ShaunWild  I feel an SSCCE would be of much more user here.

Comment: But wouldn't both be better?

Comment: How could everything fit in the window if the window is too small to hold all your panels? What would you like to happen? A scrollbar appearing? You can't stuff 12 eggs inside a box of 6.

Comment: @JB Nizet , I understand your point . I am asking is there a sound way to adjust the size of the panel and the element in the panel to fit the current window size other than hardcode it to a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

If you're adding the panel to the JFrame, it may not size correctly, try setting the panel as the JFrames content pane.
Instead of:

```
frame.add(mainPanel)
```

Do:

```
frame.setContentPane((JComponent)mainPanel);
```

I hope this helps :)

ALSO
Did you add the layout manager to the JPanel or to the JFrame? if you set it on the JFrame, just add a layout manager to your JPanel instead!

Comment: Hi Shaun , I am adding the mainPanel into another Jpanel which contains a grid layout therefore it does not have the setcontentpane method. Thanks.